# Is pressure extensive or intensive?

Tags: thermodynamics

I've learnt that pressure is an intensive measure,

but I have also learnt that pressure can be added (partial pressures), which doesn't make sense since intensive variables are non-additive.

Where is the flaw in my understanding?

Comment: It is a *the* constituting feature of partial pressures that they add up to the total pressure. You have no choice about it. And you cannot change one p.p. independently of the others, you always also have to readjust the absolute pressure.

Comment: Btw. other intensive variables can be added, too. Concentrations, for example, but if you actually, physically *mix* the two concentrations, you get their average. That's the point, imho, extensive properties add up when you physically combine objects in a single act.

Comment: @Karl thank you, your most recent comment cleared the doubt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right that intensive properties are not additive like the properties which depend on the extent of the system. Pressure is indeed an intensive property because it is force divided by an extensive quantity (area). Now partial pressure is an interesting property. It is a hypothetical construct which cannot be directly or "experimentally" measured in a mixture of gases yet it can be *calculated* for individual gases in that mixture.

The basis of calculation of partial pressure is the number of particles in the container of each gas (hence an partial pressure originates from the number of particles of gas-A and gas-B).  Greater the number of particles of each gas in a container of fixed volume, greater is the *calculated* partial pressure of each component. The number of particles in a container determine the partial pressure which is an extensive property and hence partial pressures are additive.

Wikipedia explains the limitations of classifying quantities as extensive or intensive.
Consider reading the Journal of Chemical Education Article (free download from Google Scholar)
Redlich, "*Intensive and Extensive Properties*" J. Chem. Educ., 1970, 47 (2), 154–156. Redlich says that this classification is an incredible source of confusion in thermodynamics. I feel that he is not wrong.

> The general validity of the division of physical properties into extensive and intensive kinds has been addressed in the course of science. Redlich noted that, although physical properties and especially thermodynamic properties are most conveniently defined as either intensive or extensive, these two categories are not all-inclusive and some well-defined physical properties conform to neither definition. Redlich also provides examples of mathematical functions that alter the strict additivity relationship for extensive systems, such as the square or square root of volume, which may occur in some contexts, albeit rarely used.

```
> Other systems, for which standard definitions do not provide a simple
> answer, are systems in which the subsystems interact when combined.
> Redlich pointed out that the assignment of some properties as
> intensive or extensive may depend on the way subsystems are arranged.
> For example, if two identical galvanic cells are connected in
> parallel, the voltage of the system is equal to the voltage of each
> cell, while the electric charge transferred (or the electric current)
> is extensive. However, if the same cells are connected in series, the
> charge becomes intensive and the voltage extensive. The IUPAC
> definitions do not consider such cases.
> 
> Some intensive properties do not apply at very small sizes. For
> example, viscosity is a macroscopic quantity and is not relevant for
> extremely small systems. Likewise, at a very small scale color is not
> independent of size, as shown by quantum dots, whose color depends on
> the size of the "dot".
```

Comment: I feel it is more useful as a descriptive, or experimental support. It is more a useful view, than a view that reveals something about the universe in itself. Extensive properties are very often those we can measure with reasonable efficiency and precision. We can then use the maxwell relations to transpose to intensive variables, which for some reason tends to tell us more about what is actually going on.

Comment: I think voltage or current should not be regarded as intensive or extensive. *Charge* is clearly an extensive property. Generally imho the classification ex/intensive is an educationally useful concept, but it is not fundamental, and one must be (and make the pupils aware of its) limited applicability, i.e. it belongs into basic thermodynamics, and that's it.

Comment: Yes, Karl. This is the indeed a good summary.

Comment: The last paragraph above is a bit weird (it's from Redlich, right?). Almost none of the classic intensive thermodynamic properties makes sense on a microscopic scale, I only mention *temperature*. Even most extensive properties fail, like entropy, or at least become illdefined. The only two which are beyond doubt are charge and spin, and mass (let's ignore relativistic nonsense ;-)). *Viscosity* however seems to make no sense on a microscopic scale, however you can predict the behaviour of small particles in a fluid phase *very well* if you know the macroscopic viscosity. Same goes for T. ;)

Comment: Yes, very true. The quoted paras are from Wikipedia.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss the utility of the concepts of intensive and extensive properties. Yes, there are corner cases to which they don't apply.  But that doesn't mean that, outside of those, they can't be defined precisely, and used formally.  See Chapter 1 of Callen's *Thermodynamics and an Introduction to Thermostatistics*, as well as my answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/142206/if-x-and-y-are-2-extensive-properties-of-a-system-then-is-x-y-always-intensive/142228#142228 ...

Comment: ... Indeed, I'd argue you need to understand the concept of intensive vs. extensive properties to understand why at least one of the independent variables in the total differential of a thermodynamic state function must be extensive. E.g., if you start with U = U(S, V, N), you can Legendre transform it twice to get G = G (T, p, N).  But if you Legendre transform it a third time to get some function X = X(T, p, $\mu$), X will not be a state function.